# I am trying to call on a text input with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I am trying to check to make sure a form is complete, here is a piece of my code
checking the password

```js
function checkpass()
{
   
    var pass1 = document.getElementById('pass1');
    var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2');
   
    var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
  
    var goodColor = "#66cc66";
    var badColor = "#ff6666";
  
    if(pass1.value == pass2.value){
        
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
        message.style.color = goodColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!"
    }else{
        
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
        message.style.color = badColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Do Not Match!"
    }
}
```

```html
<label >Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1">
      <p></p>
      
        <label >Verify Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" onBlur="checkpass()">
<span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
```

this works, but when I try to do something similar with the name input it does not work

```
 <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" onblur="checkname">
 <label>First Name</label> 
function checkname(){var name1 = document.getElementById('name1');if (name1 == null) {alert('entername');}}
```

If you have can tell me a simple error I have made that makes me look like a idiot that would be great, or if you could tell me a better way to do the whole thing that would also be great.
Any help you can offer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var name1 = document.getElementById('name1')
```

You forgot the .value at the end

```
var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @halonico

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for an empty name and not for a null name try with :

```
var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
if(name1.trim() == "")
```

also you need to call `checkname()` function on onblur in place of `checkname`

```js
function checkname(){
var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
if (name1.trim() == "")
{
alert('entername');
}
}
function checkpass()
{
   
    var pass1 = document.getElementById('pass1');
    var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2');
   
    var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
  
    var goodColor = "#66cc66";
    var badColor = "#ff6666";
  
    if(pass1.value == pass2.value){
        
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
        message.style.color = goodColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!"
    }else{
        
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
        message.style.color = badColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Do Not Match!"
    }
}
```

```html
 
<label >Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1">
<br/>
      
        <label >Verify Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" onBlur="checkpass()">
        <br/>
<span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
<br/>

 <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" onblur="checkname();">
 <label>First Name</label> 
 <br/>
 <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2">
 <label>Last Name</label>
```

Comment: Thank you  @Shakti Phartiyal

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this

```
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" onblur="checkname">
<label>First Name</label> 

function checkname()
{
     var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
     if (name1 == null || name1 == "") 
     {   
        alert('entername');
     }
}
```

You have miss the value when you selecting the attribute using id

Answer (score 0):

You have written this wrong

```
onblur="checkname"
```

it should be as below

```
onblur="checkname()"
```

```js
function checkname(){
  var name1 = document.getElementById('name1');
 
    console.log('name1');
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" onblur="checkname()">
 <label>First Name</label>
```

Comment: Thank you @Dhiraj

Comment: It works thank you, the: () i missed out was only in my question not my original code sorry about that. My problem was using null and missing out a value tag.       I tried your code and it worked but when I added a if statment it stoped. If I may can I get some help with this?         
      function checkname(){
var name1 = document.getElementById('name1')
if (name1.value = ""){
alert('blank');}
}else {alert(name1)}